# Matrix transformation [x/y,1,z/y,1] using constants

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

How would I transform the vector $[x,y,z,1]$ to $[x/y,1,z/y,1]$ using a $4 \times 4$ matrix with only constants (no $x,y,z)$?

[transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hmy4.png)

Comment: You can't, as that is not a linear transformation.

Comment: You can't, for the same reason why you can't transform $\,x \mapsto 1/x\,$ by multiplying with a constant in 1D.

Answer (score 0):

This is an isotropic (same over all dimensions) scaling by $1/y$. You will need the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}1/y&&&\\&1/y&&\\&&1/y&\\&&&1\end{bmatrix}$

But it is not possible to do without the $1/y$ s